# puphpet install wordpress on ubuntu server

Tags: php, wordpress, vagrant, puppet, puphpet

I am wondering if anyone has attempted to automate the deployment of wordpress and puphpet.
I am not to familiar with puphpet but I know it uses the hiera.yaml file along with the manifets and modules folder. I attempted something simple

I added this to config.yaml file and imported the wordpress module from [vagrant press](https://github.com/chad-thompson/vagrantpress)

```
wordpress:
    install: '1'
```

It looks like I may need to add something to the main manifest.pp file that puphpet generates. If anyone has attempted something like this I would appreciate any advice. Or is it better to just use yeoman instead?

**Update**

I add this to the config.yaml file

```
wordpress:
    install: '1'
```

Then in the manifest.pp file I added this at the bottom form ([wordpress vagrant box](https://github.com/rememberlenny/wordpress-vagrant-box)) and it seems to work:

```
# Begin wordpess

if $wordpress_values == undef {

  $wordpress_values = hiera('wordpress', false)

  if hash_key_equals($wordpress_values, 'install', 1) {

        # Download WordPress
        exec {"download_wordpress":
          command => "wget http://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz",
          cwd     => "/tmp",
          creates => "/tmp/latest.tar.gz",
          path    => ["/usr/bin", "/bin", "/usr/local/bin"],
          unless  => "test -f /var/www/index.php",
        }

        # Extract WordPress
        exec {"extract_wordpress":
          command => "tar xzf /tmp/latest.tar.gz",
          cwd     => "/tmp",
          creates => "/tmp/wordpress",
          path    => ["/usr/bin", "/usr/local/bin", "/bin"],
          require => Exec["download_wordpress"],
          unless  => "test -f /var/www/index.php",
        }

        # Install WordPress
        exec {"install_wordpress":
          command => "cp -r /tmp/wordpress/* /var/www/wordpress",
          cwd     => "/tmp",
          path    => ["/usr/bin", "/usr/local/bin", "/bin", "/usr/local/sbin", "/usr/sbin", "/sbin"],
          require => Exec["extract_wordpress"],
          unless  => "test -f /home/www/index.php",
        }
  }

}
```

Comment: Should not `VagrantPress` spin up a machine with working Wordpress as is? Is there a reason you are modifying anything at all?

Comment: I wanted flexibility to install other content management systems besides just wordpress and also different versions of Ubuntu other than what came out of the box with VagrantPress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PuPHPet uses hiera but not in the traditional Puppet way. You still need to actually create the Puppet code that interacts with the hiera values.